# MonoGame Save Game Location Example

Tags: monogame, savegame

I am building a game using Monogame 3.6 and Visual Studio Community 2017. Up until this point I have been serializing the data using BinarySerialization and created a custom `ContentImporter` and `ContentProcessor`.

My question is what is the standard used for saving game data and where is it saved? I attempted to use the `IntermediateSerializer` class, but that was stored in XML and is easily modified. I would like to store the game data in a file that is more difficult to tamper with, which is why I chose binary serialization.

I would also like to see an example of code that uses the standard for file paths when saving to the file system. On my development system, I can save anywhere because I am Administrator. But I would like to understand which parts of the framework are available for me to get file path information and save the data.

Comment: Are you asking where you should save game data?

Comment: Yes I am asking where the standard place is to save game data and what an example of that looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume from your question that you are working on a Windows game. The recommended location for most gamesaves would be under your users's `AppData/Roaming` folder. If you are using UWP then this is fairly easy to do as you can use the `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder` to access it using the storage classes in UWP. [The docs on this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_RoamingFolder) have a good example of saving a file.

Now that's just for Windows, each platform will have different locations and requirements for storing this kind of information. One tip I would have is have a common function for writing to files, like so:

```
public void SaveGame(string filename, string data) {
#if WINDOWS
    // save game on Windows
#elseif ANDROID
    // save game on Android
#elseif OTHER
    // ...
#endif
}
```

This reduces the hassle of maintaining file systems. As for the format of the file, that is essentially up to you, I can't think of any reason you can't format it however you want.

Comment: Does (in Windows) the exe also have permission by default in the ‘workingdir’ System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()? Many games have a ‘Saves’ folder in their folder structure.